# How to calcuate velocity of 2D object using mouse moments without a game engine?

Tags: 2d, physics, velocity

Just like the title suggests, I want to know how I would go about doing this. For example:

[image: Case #1]

In this case, I can get the average speed for the mouse per frame and that would be the velocity. Pretty straightforward, right? Well, it gets complicated when you consider that the person might pick up the object, not move the mouse position for 1/2 of the time and then move it at 100 px/s but the average speed would only end up being 50 px/s which looks wrong.

I don't actually need the code for doing this, I just need to know how to do it.

Comment if you need more information and thank you!

Comment: how the white box relate to mouse?

Comment: Huhh, there is a whole science branch behind this problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

Comment: @apple apple the white box is an object which can be influenced by the mouse.

Comment: @pptaszni could you please elaborate?

Comment: @avighnac umm elaborate even further? You already got the full article about this problem :P You are asking about the efficient way to discretely calculate a velocity (derivative of position), given the set of positions over time (and time is quantified by frames pre second). This is not a problem that can be answered straight away. The solution you proposed is called [1st order difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient). Try also some other solutions mentioned in the article and see how they work for you.

Comment: @avighnac it depend on what you want, for example, what happens when the mouse suddenly stop.

Comment: @pptaszni I don't know what calculus is :(